# Invoking mysqldump from script without password prompt

Tags: cmd, command, mysql, execute, basic

I need to execute a cmd command in Visual Basic. It's not difficult but i need to give a argument while the external Programm runs.

```
F:\mysql-5.7.13-winx64\bin\mysqldump.exe -h <ip> -u <user> -p <database> > abcd.sql
```

But after that is executed, the programm will ask for a password. So how can i do that?

Greetings, Dominic

Comment: Can you post your method of calling this in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a password at command line (not secure):

```
mysqldump.exe -h <ip> -u <user> --password="my_password" <database> > abcd.sql
```

---

You can also use [Mysql options file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html). Create `my.cnf` with credentials details:

```
[mysqldump]
host="my_host"
user="my_user"
password="my_password"
```

And provide it to mysqldump

```
mysqldump.exe <database> --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf > abcd.sql
```

Comment: Thank you:) This helped.